# How can I tell if a DOM object is out of the window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a method to know if a object (as a Div, a img, etc.) is displayed and visible by the user at the window in JavaScript / jQuery.

When I say "is displayed and visible", that's when the user don't scroll the page enough to let's the object visible (If you know what I mean). But if the user scroll the page and the div is no longer visible (is out the window) the function what I'm looking for should know that.

Comment: check for `:visible` and `:hidden`

Comment: To tell if its in the current viewport, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181040/34397

Comment: What if the element is covered by another element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [**Viewport selectors for jQuery**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) to check if the element is currently visible in the actual viewport.

[**Here's a demo**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html) to show you what I mean.

Comment: Link no longer works... :(